# Add NodeJS to a Clojure app in Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, clojure

I need the node program (NodeJS) to be present in my dynos in Heroku when I deploy a Clojure app. My app is not a NodeJS app, it cannot have a package.json for example and I don't want Heroku to validate whether it's a valid NodeJS app or not (it's not, it's a Clojure app).

What's the way to achieve this?

I tried setting up explicit buildpacks:

```
$ heroku buildpacks
=== projectx Buildpack URLs
1. https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs
2. https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-clojure
```

but still when deploying I get this error message:

```
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Multipack app detected
remote: -----> Fetching custom git buildpack... done
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to detect
```

On the logs I can see this:

```
2015-09-21T10:56:07.731335+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2015-09-21T10:56:07.731344+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation failed: no Cedar-supported app detected
2015-09-21T10:56:07.731346+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: HINT: This occurs when Heroku cannot detect the buildpack
2015-09-21T10:56:07.731347+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]:       to use for this application automatically.
2015-09-21T10:56:07.731348+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks
2015-09-21T10:58:07.541720+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2015-09-21T10:58:07.541729+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation failed: failed to detect
2015-09-21T11:00:28.651321+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2015-09-21T11:00:28.651329+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation failed: failed to detect
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `package.json` file to your project with these contents:

```
{}
```

The Node.js buildpack must detect this minimal config in order to run.

Make sure `package.json` file is committed to Git as well.

Comment: I don't really want Heroku to run Node.js in any way. My Clojure app will trigger it. Also, will having package.json help Heroku run my Clojure app?

Comment: With the empty `package.json` the node step will basically be a no-op. The buildpack will install Node.js and set up the environment so you can use `node` at build or run time.

Comment: Also, this is where your build is probably failing: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs/blob/master/bin/detect#L5

Comment: you are probably right, but having an empty package.json, makes generating a package.json, something that happens automatically when your ClojureScript app uses NodeJS and you use lein-npm to define dependencies, to fail due to "Your project already has a package.json file.  Please remove it.". I need to have the node command in Heroku without Heroku trying to validate my project as NodeJS because my project is *not* NodeJS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom build file to [override the default build behavior](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-clojure#overriding-build-behavior) of [Clojure buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-clojure) so it also installs NodeJS. Feel free to use [bin/build](https://github.com/TerjeNorderhaug/cljsnode/tree/master/bin) from my [cljsnode](https://github.com/TerjeNorderhaug/cljsnode/tree/47427f05461840569f5df1a769364aad89ac781d) project.